# How do I change sn-mathphys.bst in the Springnature template to sort alphabetically by author name?

Tags: springernature, springer

I am using Springer [sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl} to submit a paper to Celestial mechanics and Dynamical Astronomy (CMDA). I noticed that they require references to be in alphabetical order by author's last name. However, the literature seems to be sorted by citation order rather than last name. It seems that [sn-basic]{sn-jnl} would fulfill my request, but this format omits the decimal point in the journal abbreviation "." . I need to cite my literature using the [sn-mathphys] format, but I want him to be listed by last name, how do I do that?
This is the download address for the template：https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

This is the format of the CMDA
[image]

The format of [sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl} in SpringerNature templae is very similar to this, but it is not sorted alphabetically by author's last name.

Another [sn-basic]{sn-jnl} format is as follows:
[image]

It was able to list them in last name order, but the journal abbreviations and the dot in the author's name "." disappeared.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you contacted the journal's editorial office and pointed out to them that some of their formatting requirements appear to be incompatible with each other? For instance, if they require you to employ the `sn-mathphys` bibliography style, they should not also be requiring that the bibliographic entries be sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames. Do ask them directly for a ruling on how you should proceed.